# Content Delivery - Un-publish Error

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We have found a pretty strange issue in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1 Hr 1 Content Delivery in that when we un-publish content the publishing will fail.

The fail is really weird.  We have created two structure groups:

- 100 Example
- 400 Other

Each contains the same page types.  Pages contain standard metadata (text fields etc)

- If I un-publish 100 Example on the SG all files are removed
- If I un-publish 400 Other on the SG the publish task fails (CD log snippet below)
- If I go into the 400 Other SG and select all files to un-publish, this is fine
- The SG items contain no SG, or weird chars in the 'directory' name.

I see there is a hotfix -  'CD_2011.1.0.79212 - Cumulative hotfix' which is referenced in this SDL Tridion forum post (https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=7554) - but the version number strikes me as SDL Tridion 2011 Sp 1.

I've installed hotfix CD_2011.1.1.83475 (a Cumulative Hotfix), but this doens't resolve the issue.

I didn't raise this with SDL support yet as I wanted to put this info out to the community first.

My error message is:

> Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data
>   entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_26,
>   Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_26, Unable
>   to remove data entity, Unknown entity:
>   com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_26, Unknown entity:
>   com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_26 for transaction:
>   tcm:0-24997-66560 2013-02-05 15:10:18,660 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor
>   - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-24997-66560 2013-02-05 15:10:18,661 ERROR

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the structure group itself is somehow absent from the content broker. Have you tried publishing the entire SG, before unpublishing it again? If it is a data corruption problem in the broker, this might fix it.

Comment: Hi Quirijn,  Thanks, that was a good thought, but i'm afraid this is still an issue.  I'll raise it with SDL support and post the solution here.  Thanks

Comment: Did you hear back from support?

Comment: I just got same issue, I have 1051 pages, all got successfully unpublished but got error on 1 page. I get following error "Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-24659-66560, Unable to store item inside current transaction, Unable to remove data entity, Unknown entity: com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta_$$_javassist_13"